# geojson to mapbox vector tile in nodejs

Tags: geojson, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js, node-js

I'm looking for a way to transform geoJson (obtained from a query to potsgis) to mapbox vector format, serverside in nodejs, without using mapnik (I dont have access to the server and therefore cannot use mapnik, as it needs certain specific versions as seen here https://github.com/mapnik/node-mapnik/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Is there any libraries allowing to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried GeoServer http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/index.html or MapServer http://mapserver.org/development/rfc/ms-rfc-119.html.

Comment: those look like full servers, I'm currently building one inside my existing webapp server, to display a list of custom filtered point. I already fetched the geojson from my database (filtered for the correct bounding box), and I would like to transform them to mapbox vector tiles.

Comment: Does some other implementation from https://github.com/mapbox/awesome-vector-tiles suit you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I ended up using those two packages : 
https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-vt (for getting a tile from geojson)
and
https://github.com/mapbox/vt-pbf (for transforming this tile into pbf)

I made a quick module from that (maybe not ready for production use, but hey, it is a good start) : https://github.com/philippeauriach/vector-tiles-generator

Answer (score 2):

With PostGIS >2.4.0, you can also convert your geometries to mapbox vector tiles directly. For more information, see http://postgis.net/docs//ST_AsMVT.html